# oracle SQL procedure error not ended properly

Tags: oracle

I  am trying to select the total number of each value in column paxtype with the following letters m,f,i,c but my error is sql not ended properly

```
(select b.PAXTYPE from xxxx b, xxx a)
(case b.PAXTYPE
    when 'M' then count('M')
    when 'F' then count('F')
    when 'I' then count('I')
    when 'C' then count('C')
    END)
where a.date_key=to_char(b.FLIGHTDATE,'RRRRMMDD')
and a.FLTNUM_KEY= trim(substr(b.flightnumber,3))
and a.origin=b.frm
and a.destination=b.too
--and a.date_key=20170801
--and fightnumber = '100'
and trim(a.cancelled) is null
and rownum = 1
)
```

Comment: actually in this code i want to get the total number of m,f,i,c in this column paxtype please help

Comment: There is no procedure in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly You are not using the correct sql syntax. Also, there are several other problems with your query.

- Table names should come after columns in `select` .
- You need to use group by since you need `count`
- There is no need for `CASE` block
- why is `ROWNUM = 1` required?

  This query should work fine for your requirement.

  ```
  SELECT b.PAXTYPE, COUNT (b.PAXTYPE)
            FROM xxxx b, xxx a
           WHERE     a.date_key = TO_CHAR (b.FLIGHTDATE, 'RRRRMMDD')
                 AND a.FLTNUM_KEY = TRIM (SUBSTR (b.flightnumber, 3))
                 AND a.origin = b.frm
                 AND a.destination = b.too
                 --and a.date_key=20170801
                 --and fightnumber = '100'
                 AND TRIM (a.cancelled) IS NULL
        --and rownum = 1  # Why was it required?
        GROUP BY b.PAXTYPE;
  ```

Additionally, If you need only  the counts for `M,F,I,C`  then add `AND b.PAXTYPE IN ('M','F','I','C')` before `group by`